# Modifying Excel document using python and openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, excel, automation, openpyxl

I am trying to clear a sheet in an Excel document using the Openpyxl library, however the excel document in question has links to other documents. Once the program has run and I open the Excel document, I am notified that the file is damaged and more specifically the damage relates to removal of the original links that were present in the original Excel document.

The code I use is seen below:

```
def import_data(source_location, xplan_export, workbook):

    os.chdir(source_location)


    read_csv = pd.read_csv(xplan_export, encoding='latin-1')
    # print(read_csv)

    vworkbook= openpyxl.load_workbook(workbook, read_only=False)

    sheet = vworkbook['Xplan_Export']


    # clear Xplan Export sheet in  workbook of interest
    for row in sheet.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            cell.value = None
    
    
    vworkbook.save(workbook)
```

I would like to get around this to ensure that the original links remain in the output of the functions above.

Comment: Delete the worksheet and replace it with a new one.

Answer (score 0):

If there are links in the excel, the style will be set to `Hyperlink`. You can see more details on how to set this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41160818/hyperlink-not-working-through-openpyxl). So, you need to remove the data as well as the formatting. I was able to remove the data (the URL text) and the hyperlink by adding this additional line right below the `cell.value = 'None'`. After removing the data, type this (inside the loop)...

```
cell.style = 'Normal'
```

This will remove the ALL formatting and worked correctly... Hope this is what you are looking for.